# What is the reassembly path of a HTTP response?

Tags: linux, networking, http, tcpip

I am trying to understand how operating systems generally implement reassembly of network requests. From my best understanding the following is true:

A HTTP request is made at the application layer using some HTTP library. This HTTP library is really a wrapper for some socket implementation by the OS.

A "transmitting" socket is instantiated using the HTTP request's destination and source.

A "receiving" socket is instantiated using the device's IP address and a randomized (free) port.

The HTTP message is "sent" using the "transmitting" socket's file descriptor.

The socket's "send" method, sends the message to the OS's TCP implementation.

The TCP implementation segments the HTTP message, prepending the destination port (provided when instantiating the socket) and the source port. (I assume this is somehow passed around depending on implementation.) Once the HTTP message has been segmented and the TCP headers appended to it, the TCP segments are then passed to the OS's IP implementation.

The TCP segments are prepended with IP headers. The IP destination address was provided when instantiating the socket. (Again I assume the source IP address is passed around depending on implementation.)

The IP packets are then wrapped with Ethernet headers, sent to the router, sent to the server, the server processes the request, and sends back the response.

This is where my understanding breaks down on what exactly happens in the reassembly process.

How does the response make it back to the receive buffer of the "receiving" socket, more once the IP packet makes it back to the device?

Obviously headers drop off, but what steps are taken to get it back to specifically the receive buffer of the "receiving" socket, and then from the socket back to the Application?

PS I am hoping for more technical implementation detail than just "IP reassembles it" or "TCP reassembles it" and passes it up to the next layer. I am hoping to understand how exactly that takes place instead of just theoretically (though I do understand it is OS specific).

Edit:

To bring more clarity to the subject, I would note my references to socket and any socket method refer to the Linux OS.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79429/discussion-on-question-by-cg14-what-is-the-reassembly-path-of-a-http-response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good find by Mike Penningtion (in the [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1334466/what-is-the-reassembly-path-of-a-http-response#comment1995415_1334466)) finding a detailed technical description of the path of a request down the Network Stack and back up (specific to Linux OS 2005).

[A more detailed look, where the following steps were extracted from](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/netreads/path-of-packet/Network_stack.pdf):

Note, while the steps listed is not nearly as detailed as the document mentioned above, approximately the steps are:

The OS has a dedicated file descriptor for ethernet rx port,

```
The rx ring is a ring in the kernel memory where the network card transfers the incoming packet through DMA. The raw data which is stored in the rx ring structure is either copied into a sk buff structure.
```

This then fires an ISR to move the packet to the Network layer. Note, this chooses whether to process the packet or forward it (which was interesting as I imagine perhaps this is how enabling forwarding works, such as for VPNs)

If valid, it moves to the IP Layer. It checks its protocol (from the IP header) and if the protocol is TCP, calls the `tcp v4 rcv`fucntion, therby moving to the TCP Layer.

And this part is crucial:

```
The next step for this function is to find an open socket for this incoming packet,
```

this is done by calling the `tcp v4 lookup`, in the following segment of code:

```
sk = __tcp_v4_lookup(skb->nh.iph->saddr, th->source,
skb->nh.iph->daddr, ntohs(th->dest),
tcp_v4_iif(skb));
```

Essentially, I gather there is a LUT mapping the TCP socket to the source and destination address/ports of the socket connection, as indicated by that function call.

If there is a valid socket, the data is put into `tcp_data_queue` to continue up the stack for Application consumption.

Answer (score 0):

(from the [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1334466/what-is-the-reassembly-path-of-a-http-response#comment1995417_1334466))

> I get encapsulation. So lets say the OS has a dedicated file descriptor 
>   that is open on the dedicated ethernet Rx port. It strips the ethernet 
>   header off a frame and passes it to some IP parse function, to strip the 
>   destination IP. It puts this in some struct, then sends it and the struct to 
>   the TCP layer. Here it strips it off the destination port and puts it in the 
>   same struct. Here, there has to be some mapping to the sockets file descriptor 
>   based on port and ip to put the data in a buffer assigned to the file 
>   descriptor. Thats my best go at it. But Id like to know what actually happens.

A rather old version of what you're looking for is here: [Linux network stack](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/netreads/path-of-packet/Network_stack.pdf). I'm trying to find something newer than a 2005 description because some of the linux guts changed since then. Most of the socket buffering information is kept in a structure called an [`sk_buff`](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re498.html), which is a linux structure that holds pointers to the TCP socket handle, as well as all the socket read / write buffers.

As the linux NIC driver receives information from the NIC on a given socket, it looks up the buffer space off the `sk_buff` instance (named `skb`), and dumps the data into the buffers pointed to by the `skb`.